# Google Analytics Android SDK / Exceptions report : "myParser represents your implementation of ExceptionParser"

Tags: android, exception, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have implemented in my project the exception reporting feature of Google Analytics (Android SDK) described here :

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/exceptions?hl=fr

I would like to use ExceptionParser as explained at the bottom of the page but I don't understand what they mean by :

```
// Where myParser represents your implementation of ExceptionParser.
ExceptionParser parser = new myParser(context);
```

What should I write in the myParser class ?? Why this class is not part of the Google Analytics SDK ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They say that `ExceptionParser` is an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) and has only 1 method: `getDescription(String threadName, Throwable t)`.

So, to get the most relevant description of the exception you may create a new class that implements that interface and overrides `getDescription()`.

Something like this:

```
public class MyParser implements ExceptionParser{
   @Override
   public String getDescription(String threadName, Throwable t){
      return threadName+", "+t.get..... 
   }
}
```

(Note that I'm not sure that return type of `getDescription()` is `String`. You should put the appropriate return type)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks !

I used Andy Res answer. My full getDescription method is :

```
public String getDescription(String threadName, Throwable t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String description = "threadName = "
        + threadName
        + "\ngetMessage()= " + t.getMessage()
        + "\ngetLocalizedMessage()=" + t.getLocalizedMessage()
        + "\ngetCause()=" + t.getCause()
        + "\ngetStackTrace()=" + t.getStackTrace();

        return description;

    }
```